# HTTP manual Client not writing to disk properly JAVA

Tags: java, sockets, http, file-io

I am trying to build a manual HTTP client (using sockets) along with a cache and I cant seem to figure out why the files are not saving to disk properly. It works pretty good for HTML files, but cant seem to work for other files types that re not text based like .gif. Could anyone tell me why? I am quite new to HTTP protocol and Socket programming in general.

The loop to grab the response.

```
    InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
    PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

    ArrayList<Byte> dataIn = new ArrayList<Byte>();
    ArrayList<String> stringData = new ArrayList<String>();

    //Indices to show the location of certain lines in arrayList
    int blankIndex = 8;
    int lastModIndex = 0;

    int byteBlankIndex = 0;

    try
    {
        //Get last modified date
        long lastMod = getLastModified(url);
        Date d = new Date(lastMod);

        //Construct the get request
        outputStream.print("GET "+ "/" + pathName + " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
        outputStream.print("If-Modified-Since: " + ft.format(d)+ "\r\n");
        outputStream.print("Host: " + hostString+"\r\n");
        outputStream.print("\r\n");
        outputStream.flush();

        //Booleans to prevent duplicates, only need first occurrences of key strings
        boolean blankDetected = false;
        boolean lastModDetected = false;

        //Keep track of current index
        int count = 0;

        int byteCount = 0;

        //While loop to read response
        String buff = "";
        byte t;
        while ( (t = (byte) inputStream.read()) != -1)
        {
            dataIn.add(t);
            //Check for key lines

            char x = (char) t;
            buff = buff + x;

            //For the first blank line (signaling the end of the header)
            if(x == '\n')
            {
                stringData.add(buff);

                if(buff.equals("\r\n") && !blankDetected)
                {
                    blankDetected = true;
                    blankIndex = count;
                    byteBlankIndex = byteCount + 2;
                }

                //For the last modified line
                if(buff.contains("Last-Modified:") && !lastModDetected)
                {
                    lastModDetected = true;
                    lastModIndex = count;
                }

                buff = "";
                count++;
            }
            //Increment count
            byteCount++;
        }

    }
```

The the code to parse through response and write file to disk.

```
        String catalogKey = hostString+ "/" + pathName;

        //Get the directory sequence to make
        String directoryPath = catalogKey.substring(0, catalogKey.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

        //Make the directory sequence if possible, ignore the boolean value that results
        boolean ignoreThisBooleanVal = new File(directoryPath).mkdirs();

        //Setup output file, and then write the contents of dataIn (excluding header) to the file
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(new File(catalogKey)),true);

        for(int i = byteBlankIndex + 1 ; i < dataIn.size(); i++)
        {
            output.print(new String(new byte[]{ (byte)dataIn.get(i)}, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        }


        output.close();
```

Comment: Because you are converting a byte to a char and that doesn't work for stream of binary data.

Comment: If i leave it as a byte, i get a series of numbers even on an HTML file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
byte t;
while ( (t = (byte) inputStream.read()) != -1)
```

The problem is here. It should read:

```
int t;
while ( (t = inputStream.read()) != -1)
{
    byte b = (byte)t;
    // use b from now on in the loop.
```

The issue is that a byte of `0xff` in the input will be returned to the `int` as `0xff`, but to the `byte` as -1, so you are unable to distinguish it from end of stream.

And you should use a `FileOutputStream,` not a `FileWriter`, and you should not accumulate potentially binary data into a `String` or `StringBuffer` or anything to do with `char`. As soon as you've got to the end of the header you should open a `FileOutputStream` and just start copying bytes. Use buffered streams to make all this more efficient.

Not much point in any of these given that `HttpURLConnection` already exists.

Comment: After fixing the blank byte index counter too, IT WORKS PERFECT.